# Post Two images to Web server

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

Below code i wrote for sending two images. But i failed to find the  code why its not working. i am new to iOS and even stackoverflow. Still am thinking the code is ok. just help me to find my mistake. how i modify the code to able to send two images with different services(each service have a separate url).

```
NSString *requestString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"requestUserId=%@&CategoryId=%@&Continent=%@&Country=%@&City=%@&Gender=%@&ImageName=%@&AgeRange=%@",userID,CategoryId1,continentTextfield.text,countrytextfield.text,citytextfield.text,GenderText.text,imagename,ageTextfield.text];
NSLog(@"request%@",requestString);
NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/InsertObjectImage?%@",requestString];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

// Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.

NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
[request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
[request addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData;
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);

NSURLConnection *connReq = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (connReq) {

    NSLog(@"Connection Sucessful");
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

}

else {

    NSLog(@"failed");

}

NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSLog(@"Status code: %d", [response statusCode]);
NSLog(@"respdata%@",respData);
```

if ([response statusCode]==200)
    {

```
    self.userId=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Sendd"];

    NSLog(@"recievedData%@",receivedData);

    NSString *requestString1 =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"requestUserId=%@&ImageId=%@&=ImageName%@",userID,compareId,imagename];
    NSLog(@"%@",requestString1);

    NSString *url1=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" http://37.187.152.236/UserImage.svc/UpdateObjectImage?%@",requestString1];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request1 setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url1]];
    [request1 setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // Create 'POST' MutableRequest with Data and Other Image Attachment.

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request1 setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(chosenImage, 0.2f);
    [request1 addValue:@"image/JPEG" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *body1 = [NSMutableData data];
    [body1 appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body1];

    NSData *returnData;
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Ret: %@",returnString);


    NSURLConnection *connReq = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    if (connReq) {

        NSLog(@"Connection Sucessful");
        receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];

    }

    else {

        NSLog(@"failed");

    }

    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *respData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
    NSLog(@"Status code: %d", [response statusCode]);
    NSLog(@"respdata%@",respData);


    homeViewController *homVew =[[homeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"homeViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:homVew animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566897/upload-image-from-ios-app-to-php-cant-quite-get-it-right-what-am-i-miss/23579723#23579723

Comment: i need to send to images in a moovement. @AshishKakkad

Comment: could please answer with edited code. @AshishKakkad

Comment: Use third parties. Like AFNetworking, ASIHttp, MKNetworking. You can easily integrate and utility them @user3766168

Comment: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use            Check the Sending a form POST with ASIFormDataRequest. It will helps you

Comment: You can use be this library that will work on any kind of web service: github.com/mineshpurohit/ServiceCallingUtility