# Upload image from iOS app to web server using php showing error?

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, uiimage

I captured image and display it in UIImageView .

When i try to upload image to Amazon web server am getting this error

```
Image Return String: file=test.pngerror
```

My Code

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(cell4.img.image);
NSString *urlString = @"http://myipaddress/allapps/php/test.php";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"test.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image Return String: %@", returnString]);
```

and my php script

```
 <?php
$uploaddir = 'uploads/';
$file = basename($_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

echo "file=".$file; //is empty, but shouldn't

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo $file;
}
else {
    echo "error";
}
?>
```

In my info.plist i made this change to avoid security error
these are the changes i made in plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>  
 <dict>  
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>  
 </dict>
```

Please help me to fix this

Comment: I think to send a file with name test.png  name= \"test\" and filename = \".png\"

Comment: I think here in this link you can find solution, because may be error in iphone code because php code is same like in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566897/upload-image-from-ios-app-to-php-cant-quite-get-it-right-what-am-i-miss

Answer (score -1):

It seems you change the format of image to .png by manually. Please try to upload the image with original format.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer!

Comment: by default all images are .png in ios

Comment: @testuser I didn't get your point. Didn't you added the test image in your project by yourself? From where are you getting the test.png?

Comment: please read my question, in first line i mentioned " i captured image" mean i took it through camera.

Comment: Then please check your server side script. Perhaps it's not coded to accept png format images

Comment: i think php creating problem